# CM Storm Devastator Backlight on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, backlight

I have a CM Storm Devastator and cannot get the backlight working on Mac. I have followed the instructions below :

> 1. Go here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/HID_LED_test_tool/Introduction/Intro.html
> 2. Click the little "Download sample code" button
> 3. Open the downloaded folder and go to Build / Release
> 4. Drag the HID LED test tool file to your Applications folder
> 5. Launch the OS X "Automator" program
> 6. Choose "Service" document type
> 7. Under "Library", click "Utilities", and drag "Run Shell Script" to the blank area / workflow pane.
> 8. For "selected service receives" choose "no input" in "any application" (important)
> 9. For "pass input" choose "as arguments" (important)
> 10. For "shell" choose "/bin/bash"
> 11. Paste in this script:
>
>     /Applications/HID\ LED\ test\ tool &
>       pid=$!
>       sleep 3
>       kill $pid
> 12. Click "run" to test. After 3 seconds, your keyboard should remain in a state with num lock and scroll lock enabled, and all the keys should be lit up. Yay! Continue to assign keyboard shortcut to do this.
> 13. Click "File" > "Save", "Save service as" : "Devastator LED Lighter"
> 14. Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > General > "Devastator LED Lighter"
> 15. Assign a shortcut. Scroll lock and F keys didn't work for me. I ended up choosing  "

The problems I have encountered:

1. The downloaded file is called "HID_LED_test_tool". This contains 3 files

   - HID LED test tool-Read Me.txt
   - HID LED test tool.xcodeproj
   - main.c

   Problem: it does not contain a build/release folder, so I dragged HID LED test tool.xcodeproj into the Applications folder.
2. I followed all the instructions above renaming the HID LED... file to a simple HID. The problem is that when I run the automator program as indicated above I get the reply `xxxxx is a directory.`  I cannot get around this; I have tried extracting the file within the HID LED test tool folder and then executing the automator with that file name but the exact same thing happens ....
3. When I attempt to open the project.pbxproj file in Terminal I get the response :

   ```
   Last login: Sat Feb  7 19:34:21 on ttys000
   /Applications/HID\ LED\ test\ tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj ; exit;
   Zakias-MacBook-Pro:~ zakia$ /Applications/HID\ LED\ test\ tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj ; exit;
   /Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 1: //: is a directory
   /Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 3: archiveVersion: command not found
   /Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 4: classes: command not found
   /Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 6: objectVersion: command not found
   /Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 7: objects: command not found
   /Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 9: /Applications: is a directory
   /Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
   /Applications/HID LED test tool.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: line 10: `       8DD76F770486A8DE00D96B5E /* main.c in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 08FB7796FE84155DC02AAC07 /* main.c */; settings = {ATTRIBUTES = (); }; };'
   logout


   [Process completed]
   ```

Comment: Try the solution posted here http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181975/38141

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the build folder, you just need the HID LED test tool.xcodeproj file.

1. Make sure you have Xcode installed on your Mac. You can download it from the App Store.
2. Open it and hit the play button on Xcode. It will flash on your keyboard and just hit the stop botton when everything is lit up.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need Xcode, the source is available on a (probably unofficial) [mirror](http://sdg.mesonet.org/people/brad/XCode3/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleSnowLeopard.CoreReference.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/#samplecode/HID_LED_test_tool/Introduction/Intro.html)

Just open the 'build>release double click 'HID LED test tool', the keyboard will start blinking then just press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>