# Assigning a key to light up CM Storm Devastator keyboard problem

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I followed the steps to make the CM Storm Devastator keyboard backlights turn on (using [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156273/os-x-cm-storm-devastator-keyboard-doesnt-light-up/181975#181975) tutorial). That is working. But, when I assigned a key to toggle the backlight, the backlight does not turn on. The key I have it assigned to is command+F14. I am on Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

First, check under: `System Preferences > Keyboard` and see if your "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" option is checked.

If the box is *not* checked, you will need to hold down `Fn` as well - this means that it your keyboard combination should be `Fn+Cmd+F14`.

If the box *is* checked (which means pressing F1/F2 doesn't affect brightness, F11/F12 doesn't affect volume etc) then you may want to check your configurations and go over the steps in the tutorial again.

I hope this helps.