# Windows Gaming RGB keyboard - Scroll Lock on Mac does not enable RGB lights

Tags: mac, keyboard

I'm a mac user and I just bought a new RGB windows keyboard. In order to enable the RGB light, I have to press "Scroll Lock". But every time I press, it keeps decreasing the brightness. It doesn't work because it's a windows keyboard.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Please be more specific about the brand and model of keyboard you're attempting to use. More than likely, you'll need drivers of some sort to enable this keyboard.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/damieng/setledsmac. It can be used to toggle the scroll lock LED, which may or may not trigger the RGB functionality of your keyboard. I think you may be able to hack the script to enable RGBs. There's a few threads floating around out there on this very topic.

Comment: Also check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/156273/os-x-cm-storm-devastator-keyboard-doesnt-light-up/181975#181975